# Java Lab Project

Tags: java

So I am currently working on a lab for class. I'll attach the lab below:

For this lab, you will use a series of nested if-else or if-else-if statements in order to convert a Roman Numeral number into its String word form. The numerals we are concerned with are I, II, III, IV, V, VI, VII, VIII, which coincide with One, Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight. Numbers outside of this range are denied – you must tell the user that they are denied as input.

Your code must not fall for inputs like ‘I am the best roman numeral, ‘IIIlikefish’, or ‘VIII is delicious.’ Those inputs should be denied just like an input outside of I to VIII would be

What are possible ways to avoid falling for fake inputs?

Also, I currently have 8 different if statements, is there a faster way to do this?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RomanNumeralChecker {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

      String romanNum;

      System.out.println("Please enter a Roman Numeral between the values 1 and 8:");
      romanNum = keyboard.next();

      if (romanNum.equalsIgnoreCase("I")){
         System.out.println(romanNum + " represents the number \"One\"");
      }
      else if (romanNum.equalsIgnoreCase("II")){
         System.out.println(romanNum + " represents the number \"Two\"");
      }
      else if (romanNum.equalsIgnoreCase("III")){
         System.out.println(romanNum + " represents the number \"Three\"");
      }
      else if (romanNum.equalsIgnoreCase("IV")){
         System.out.println(romanNum + " represents the number \"Four\"");
      }
      else if (romanNum.equalsIgnoreCase("V")){
         System.out.println(romanNum + " represents the number \"Five\"");
      }
      else if (romanNum.equalsIgnoreCase("VI")){
         System.out.println(romanNum + " represents the number \"Six\"");
      }
      else if (romanNum.equalsIgnoreCase("VII")){
         System.out.println(romanNum + " represents the number \"Seven\"");
      }
      else if (romanNum.equalsIgnoreCase("VIII")){
         System.out.println(romanNum + " represents the number \"Eight\"");
      }
      else {
         System.out.println("Sorry, but " + romanNum + " is out of the desired range.");
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: you can use only If-else statement ? You need to use HasMap .with loop

Comment: We haven't talked about that at all yet, I'll look into it

Comment: This is probably the most simplest and fastest way. What do you mean by faster? Your cpu can do million of such calculation like in less than second. You can use switch statement to make it look a bit nicer but there won't be a performance gain.

Comment: Faster for the me to input, not the hardware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reduce the number of if statement by using Map.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;

public class RomanNumeralChecker {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<String, String> m = new HashMap<String, String>();
        m.put("I", "One");
        m.put("II", "Two");
        m.put("III", "Three");
        m.put("IV", "Four");
        m.put("V", "Five");
        m.put("VI", "Six");
        m.put("VII", "Seven");
        m.put("VIII", "Eight");

        System.out.println("Please enter a Roman Numeral between the values 1 and 8:");

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String romanNum = keyboard.next();

        String num = m.get(romanNum);
        if (num != null) {
            System.out.println(romanNum + " represents the number \"" + num + "\"");   
        } else {
            System.out.println("Sorry, but " + romanNum + " is out of the desired range.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The requirement clearly says the "you will use a series of nested if-else or if-else-if statements in order to convert a Roman Numeral number into its String word form".

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine for what you need it to do. There are ways to check for valid entry other than what you have implemented but they may be a bit more involved. Professors tend to become upset (Maybe mines was just a jerk) when student do more than what is required for a coding lab.

Comment: @LukeAuslender You've already taken care of this case. "The String equalsIgnoreCase() method compares the two given strings on the basis of the content of the string irrespective of the case of the string. It is like equals() method but doesn't check case. If any character is not matched, it returns false otherwise it returns true."

Answer (score 0):

In the code shown by @nakano531, there's no way that a "trick input" will work. If it what they input, literally does not match the HashMap, it will prompt them that they have entered an invalid answer. ( Don't have the necessary reputation points to say this under his answer, but I wanted to let you know)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is using

```
romanNum = keyboard.next();
```

This will return first word from the given input.But you should use .

```
romanNum = keyboard.nextLine();
```

Which will read the entire String provided by the use like the ones( ‘I am the best roman numeral, ‘IIIlikefish’, or ‘VIII is delicious.’) you mentioned.

Comment: I need the program to recognize the ( ‘I am the best roman numeral, ‘IIIlikefish’, or ‘VIII is delicious.’) Strings as invalid. However, I am currently using keyboard.next(); and it is still recognizing them as "One".

Comment: That is what I am saying if you use nextLine instead of next it will treat above mentioned string as invalid. If you use next the if you pass string like "I am the best "it will return I so it will convert it to Roman numeral as it passes the equals check you are making. If you use nextLine it will return full string and equals check fails.

Comment: I get what you're saying and you just saved me a lot of frustration. 1000 upvotes to you! <3

Comment: Can you check the code I posted about? I've moved onto JOption windows but can't get them to work properly.

Comment: I have commented on your answer. But you should have updated your question with JOptionPane way you are implementing.. Rather than as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

i Hope this will help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

```
    public class answer {
    public static void main (String[]args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String a0 = sc.nextLine();
    String[]a1 = {"I","II","III","IV","V","VI","VII","VIII"};
    String[]a2 = {"One","Two","Three","Four","Five","Six","Seven","Eight"};
    for(int i=0;i<a1.length;i++) {
    if(a0.equals(a1[i])) {
        System.out.println(a0+" represent "+a2[i]);     
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("You Type smth wrong");
    }
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is where we are now. The issue is I can't get the JOption windows to pop up after taking the users input.

```
public class RomanNumeralChecker {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        String romanNum;

        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Please enter a Roman Numeral between the values 1 and 8: ");
        romanNum = keyboard.nextLine();

        if (romanNum.charAt(0) == 'I') {
            if (romanNum.equalsIgnoreCase("I"))
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,romanNum + " represents the number \"One\"");
            if (romanNum.equalsIgnoreCase("II"))
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,romanNum + " represents the number \"Two\"");
            if (romanNum.equalsIgnoreCase("III"))
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,romanNum + " represents the number \"Three\"");
            if (romanNum.equalsIgnoreCase("IV"))
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,romanNum + " represents the number \"Four\"");
        }
        else if (romanNum.charAt(0) == 'V') {
            if (romanNum.equalsIgnoreCase("V"))
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,romanNum + " represents the number \"Five\"");
            if (romanNum.equalsIgnoreCase("VI"))
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,romanNum + " represents the number \"Six\"");
            if (romanNum.equalsIgnoreCase("VII"))
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,romanNum + " represents the number \"Seven\"");
            if (romanNum.equalsIgnoreCase("VIII"))
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,romanNum + " represents the number \"Eight\"");
        }
        else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Not in valid range.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are using showInputDialog() you don't require a Scanner to read the input. You can simply write romanNum=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Please enter a Roman Numeral between the values 1 and 8: ");